# Reading and Writing to documents or other files in Google Drive using gnome account

Tags: online-accounts, google-drive

So I added my Google Drive using [gnome-online accounts](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeOnlineAccounts) in ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Now if I make changes to the directory (e.g add a new file or remove it etc.) it syncs fine.

But whenever, I try to open a document(eg.a pdf file), the default **Document Viewer** tries to download it first and then let me read/edit it. When done, I have to upload it again to get it synced!  I tried using **Okular** but it simply can't open it.

Is there any way to seamlessly open and edit files (for my case I need to edit some pdf files and docs) in Google Drive as can be done in Windows (using it just as a regular folder)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use grive2. https://github.com/vitalif/grive2

Comment: Certainly worthy filing as an issue to the Gnome developers. This is not how it should work.

Comment: I use google-drive-ocamlfuse. The built-in Gnome way supports the basics but this way is more-or-less just like any other filesystem/mount. You can also use sync tools like rsync etc. https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

Comment: @codlord Thanks. This works exactly like I wanted.